# Handling multiple tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got many sets of divs. e.g.: `furniture1, furniture2, furniture3....`, `stationary1, stationary2, stationary3...`, etc...

I need to have a unique tooltip for each ID. What is the easiest way to do this?

e.g.:

```
$("#furniture1").tooltip({ title : '$560' });
$("#furniture2").tooltip({ title : '$785' });
$("#furniture3").tooltip({ title : '$325' });
```

Is it possible to do this using 2 arrays (ID array and TITLE array)?

**EDIT:**

Using JSON to populate arrays:

```
var tt;

$.ajax({url: '/toolt.json'}).done(function(t) {
    tt = t;
      //how to combine with a loop?
});
```

Comment: In bootstrap documentation you could specify the tooltips via data-attributes. For example like this: `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="YOur title or data"` and on document ready you could load all the tooltips like this `$(function () { $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just go through ids and put the tooltip:

```
var ids = ["furniture1", "furniture2", "furniture3"]
var titles = ["$560", "$785", "$325"]

for(var i = 0; i < ids.length;i++ ){
    $("#"+ids[i]).tooltip({title:titles[i]})
}
```

To make these 2 arrays from the json:

```
var ids = [], titles = []

for(var i=0; i < t.length;i++){
    ids.push(t[i][0]);
    titles.push(t[i][1])
}
```

Comment: looks good. If I store the array values externally, is it possible to populate the two arrays using the external file?

Comment: Sure, if its a json file you can do a request and fill the arrays

Comment: See my edit. If I bring in the json how would I combine it with your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fergoso what do you have in t?

Comment: toolt.json would be as: `[ [ "furniture1", "$560"], [ "furniture2", "$785"],]`